# Can't add password to redis-64 on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, redis

I installed [`redis-64`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64) from chocolatey using `cinst redis-64`.

I've set `requirepass` to `mypassword` in *C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64\redis.windows.conf* and ran `redis-server.exe` on my cli.

My node script looks like this:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const config = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '6666',
    password: 'mypassword'
};
const redisClient = redis.createClient(config);
```

Everytime I start it, I get the following warning in stdout:

> node_redis: Warning: Redis server does not require a password, but a
>   password was supplied.

Is this a bug in the library? If not, how can I set a password on redis for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to pass the configuration file every time you start the server ಠ_ಠ

```
> redis-server.exe C:\relative\or\full\path\to\redis.windows.conf
```